# Parallel linear algebra with arbitrary precision

Tags: numerics, linear-algebra, parallelization, arbitrary-precision

Is it possible to do parallel linear algebra with arbitrary precision within Mathematica (in a simple manner, as is done for the machine precision)?

Comment: Good question, but unfortunately I fear that the answer might be "no". *Mathematica* is mostly single-threaded; for machine precision it's only parallelized because the MKL is used. Things are improving, though, so you may be lucky in version 9 (but don't hold your breath). Other than that you'll have to roll your own or call out to a library, I guess.

Comment: I don't get it. Isn't it obvious to use parallelization in coputation intensive algoriths?

Comment: Yes, I suppose so. Why don't you write your own arbitrary precision linear algebra library or parallelize *Mathematica*'s implementation, then? I'm being facetious, of course. WRI has many very clever, talented, and hard-working people, but this is easier said than done. In fact I don't know of a single program or library that offers what you want, *Mathematica*-hosted or otherwise. That presumably reflects the reality that "obvious" does not imply "trivial".

Comment: So the question is what is nontrivial in doing this?

Comment: I don't exactly know what the difficulties are and don't have time now to find out, but this is a topic of current research. I suspect the main issue is to find decompositions of the various problems that are both efficient and numerically stable. The people over at [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) will know more and may be able to suggest approaches for the particular problems of interest to you.